# AsyncIO run in executor using ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I tried to combine blocking tasks and non-blocking (I/O bound) tasks using `ProcessPoolExecutor` and found it's behavior pretty unexpected.

```
class BlockingQueueListener(BaseBlockingListener):
    def run(self):
        # Continioulsy listening a queue
        blocking_listen()

class NonBlockingListener(BaseNonBlocking):
    def non_blocking_listen(self):
        while True:
           await self.get_message()


def run(blocking):
    blocking.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    blocking = BlockingQueueListener()
    non_blocking = NonBlockingListener()
    future = loop.run_in_executor(executor, run(blocking))
    loop.run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(
            non_blocking.main(),
            future
        )
    )
```

I was expecting that both tasks will have control concurrently, but blocking task started in `ProcessPoolExecutor` blocks and never return control. How could it happen? What the proper way to combine normal coroutines and futures started in multiprocessing executor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
future = loop.run_in_executor(executor, run(blocking))
```

Will actually run the blocking function and give its result to the executor.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor), you need to pass the function explicitly followed by its arguments.

```
 future = loop.run_in_executor(executor, run, blocking)
```